# How to adjust swipe sensitivity on Samsung Galaxy Devices?

Tags: samsung, settings, touchscreen, gestures

I recently owned a Samsung Galaxy S21 (Ultra), before having a OnePlus 6. Everything is fine, but I really dislike how sensitive it is for swipe gestures. Scrolling to the side is interpreted as scrolling up/down if I do not swipe with a 90° angle.

Furthermore, while scrolling I can't hit buttons, it is interpreted as further scrolling. But the delay for the end of the scrolling is very long.

Do you have any idea how to get some normal touchscreen/swipe behavior on this smartphone without rooting it?